# OS X Numbers. Column labels to numbers

Tags: macos, numbers

Hi
I am using Numbers on OS X

It show me column names with letters
[image]

But I want to show it with numbers, like Rows.
[image]

Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  I have to ask, Why?  Even if it were possible (I don't think even Excel has this feature) it would cause confusion in cell references. "A1" would become "11".  What is the specific reason you need numbers as column id's?

Comment: Because I have very big csv file. And I want to see, for example what in 1234th column,

Comment: @bjbk Excel do have this feature for decades. Done in prefs. called "Use R1C1 reference style"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, what is done is to create a **Column Header**.  You already have a perfect example of this in the table shown in your question. Row 1 contains field names for each data record.  i.e.: "Image", "whale_00", etc. (See ["Work with Rows and Columns"](https://help.apple.com/numbers/mac/3.5/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/tan504013a74) in Numbers Help)

- Select **Row 1** and convert to **Header Row**

[image: Converting row to header]

If you wish, you can create a header row with you own number system. This would be much faster and less tedious than renaming the column designations.  (In answer to your question: Cannot presently be done in Numbers.) NOTE: By design, Numbers will use your *Header Row Data* in calculations so you can easily identify the data being referenced.

- Add a **Row Above** your first row.
- Enter ordinal numbers in the first and second cells.  For example: `A1 = 1, B1 = 2`
- Select both cells in the row and drag the "yellow dot" across the width of the row to number each column.
- Convert this to a **Header Row**

[image: Auto numbering row ordinaly]

Comment: to downvoter, anything I could improve?  I don't mind a deserved down-vote, but an explanation would be nice.

Comment: Dont mind bro, Your answer is really helped me. Thank you again

Comment: Glad it helped! Cheers!

Comment: can't believe it's only way...